# Destructuring an object for an update mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I'm still new to Reactjs and Graphql. I've been trying to pass a specific object to the variables object for an update operation. I want to be able to separate the object into `ID` and other values because it's inside a component that's used by other features hence it will be easy to use the same component to carry out mutation on others as well.

I retrieved this specific object when I click on my edit tab from this code:

```
 const handleUpdate = () => {
    const updateDetails = {}
    Object.keys(formDetails).forEach(k => {
      updateDetails[k] = formDetails[k]?.id ? formDetails[k]?.value : formDetails[k]
    })
    console.log('updated data is ', updateDetails)
    onUpdate(updateDetails)
  }
```

The above code when I do `console.log` returns results like:

```
updated data is  {__typename: "NewsType", id: "c67ea940-298f-4d27-8661-57630f8812a5", name: "Gary"}
```

my `onUpdate` function is defined in another file as prop like so:

```
const onUpdate = async (items) => {
    console.log('values to insert is ', items)
    try {
      const { data } = await update({ variables: { [inputKey]: items, [inputID]: items.id } })
      if (Object.values(data)[0].ok) {
         handleModal()
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

where the `[inputKey]` and `[inputID]` are passed as prop depending on the feature we are working with but in this case, the values are `news` and `id` respectively.

my update mutation is like below:

```
const [update] = useMutation(updateOperation)
```

where my `updateOperation` is also passed in as a prop to make it more general to be used by other features.

my grapqhql query passed to my `updateOperation` is like below:

```
export const UPDATE_NEWS = gql`
  mutation updateNews($news: NewsUpdateGenericType!, $id: ID!){
    updateNews(news: $news, id: $id) {
     ok
    }  
  } `
```

I've tried so many concepts like using

```
Object.keys(values).foreach((id, value) => {
....})
```

and `Object.entries(values)`.

I'm really finding it difficult to make this update feature work... any ideas on the way out will be highly appreciated

Comment: I'm quite confused on what you want to achieve here. Which object do you want to separate into ID and values from your question? Can you explain where the "updateData" variable in "handleUpdate()" method came from? Also, using variables named "inputKey" and "inputID" at the same time makes it a bit tricky to follow for me. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @Ziwon I was suppose to use "updateDetails" not "updateData" ... sorry about that... I'm trying to use it to save each form data I have depending on the feature I'm dealing with (basically making it general as well so it can be used by other features that has form). I'm trying to update specific data using graphql mutation and it requires an ID as well as the values to be updated... I'm finding it difficult to seperate my object into ID and other values so it can be used as an argument for my update operation. I'm trying to make all my components reusable basically

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, you want to use 1 single useMutation for ALL kinds of "update operations", right? I'm not sure if that's a good idea. This suggests  you definitely will not be using TypeScript for your GraphQL queries. So my answer to your question would be to just use a mutation function for each "update operation". This way you'll be able to utilise TypeScript later on if you choose to. The only way I see this working is if you're updating one specific type of object with this. If you want to support multiple type of objects, I don't think this will work.

Comment: Not really....  the use mutation hook is in a component I plan to reuse for the features... so I'm basically passing a variable to it as a prop. Anytime am dealing with a new feature that requires mutation I just pass it as a prop to the component... hence the need to destructure my object so I can always reuse it

Comment: Are you just going to change one type of object? Or for ALL kinds of objects?

Comment: I'm trying to structure my mutation in such a way that if I pass an object in the future that has more properties than the present object it can handle it effortlessly. All it needs is just the ID and it can spread other values for the other parameter and still run correctly

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to have one mutation function for all. I've tried to achieve something similar with one of my projects. However, I only managed with only one object type - the **User**. I used Hasura with TypeScript, so the project setting may be very difficult to yours but hopefully it can give an idea.

**Mutation gql**

```
export const UPDATE_USER = gql`
  ${USER_FIELDS}
  mutation update_user($id: String!, $changes: users_set_input) {
    update_users_by_pk(
      pk_columns: {id: $id}, 
      _set: $changes
    ) {
        ...UserFields
      # id
      # name
      # ...
    }
  }
`
```

**users_set_input Type Definition**

```
export type Users_Set_Input = {
  id?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  name?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  ...
};
```

**useMutation Hook**

```
const [updateUser, { data: updateData }] = useMutation<
  Update_UserMutation
>(UPDATE_USER)
```

```
export type Update_UserMutation = { __typename?: 'mutation_root', update_users_by_pk?: Maybe<{ __typename?: 'users', id: string, name?: Maybe<string>}> };
```

**updateUser Call**

> ***targetField*** is a dynamic variable that is passed as a prop

```
updateUser({
  variables: {
    id: userId,
    changes: { [targetField]: saveValue }
  },
}
```

Comment: Like for your "updateUser", how did you seperate your object into "userID" and "saveValue" to make it reusable for other features??

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to find away to seperate my object into ID and other values.

I used the concept

```
const {id, ...otherValues} = items
```

This did the trick for me... Thanks for the efforts @Ziwon